# forecasting decimal points using ARIMA

Tags: r, arima

I am trying to forecast below data which is a ratio of a population. When I run the arima forecast I dont get the results in ratio format (see results below). I don't understand why.

Data:

```
  Date                ratio
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2018-02-01 00:00:00  1.61
 2 2018-03-01 00:00:00  0.75
 3 2018-04-01 00:00:00  0.64
 4 2018-05-01 00:00:00  0.9 
 5 2018-06-01 00:00:00  1.46
 6 2018-07-01 00:00:00  1.49
 7 2018-08-01 00:00:00  2.17
 8 2018-09-01 00:00:00  3.01
 9 2018-10-01 00:00:00  2.38
10 2018-11-01 00:00:00  2.45
11 2018-12-01 00:00:00  3.02
12 2019-01-01 00:00:00  1.2 
13 2019-02-01 00:00:00  0.61
14 2019-03-01 00:00:00  0.84
15 2019-04-01 00:00:00  0.78
16 2019-05-01 00:00:00  0.88
17 2019-06-01 00:00:00  1.09
18 2019-07-01 00:00:00  1.45
19 2019-08-01 00:00:00  0.81
20 2019-09-01 00:00:00  1.88
21 2019-10-01 00:00:00  0.88
22 2019-11-01 00:00:00  1.17
23 2019-12-01 00:00:00  1.76
```

Results:

```
forecast1
   Point Forecast      Lo 80      Hi 80      Lo 95      Hi 95
24     1577806184 1577363075 1578249293 1577128507 1578483861
25     1580422018 1579940160 1580903876 1579685080 1581158956
26     1583056151 1582469469 1583642833 1582158898 1583953404
27     1585679803 1585041517 1586318090 1584703629 1586655978
28     1588309459 1587604566 1589014352 1587231418 1589387499
29     1590935676 1590180198 1591691154 1589780272 1592091080
30     1593563862 1592755550 1594372174 1592327656 1594800068
31     1596190920 1595335983 1597045858 1594883406 1597498435
32     1598818625 1597917873 1599719376 1597441044 1600196205
33     1601445959 1600502492 1602389426 1600003051 1602888867
34     1604073505 1603088694 1605058317 1602567366 1605579645
35     1606700930 1605676707 1607725154 1605134515 1608267345
```

code below

```
autoarima <- auto.arima(mymodel[,1])

autoarima

forecast1 <- forecast(autoarima, h = 12)
plot(forecast1) 
forecast1
```

Comment: `mymodel[,1]`: you are using the first column as your time series, while you should use the second. ARIMA is predicting the next dates as per your code. Remember that R is 1-based so `1` points to the first element.

Comment: Thank you nicola, I though the first column starts with 0 like in python. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: please include the code to generate mymodel dataframe